# Spring OAUTH2 - Access token expiry time

Tags: spring, spring-security-oauth2

Is it possible to update/reset the expiry time of an access token programatically? If yes, which class/filter would be the best place to do it so that expiry time can be updated in JDBC token store.

Answer (score 10):

To update the expiry time of an access token globally you should have to create instance of the `DefaultTokenServices` & inject into the `AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer` like this :

```
public AuthorizationServerTokenServices customTokenServices(){
  TokenServices tokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
  tokenServices.setReuseAccessToken(reuseAccessToken);
  tokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore());
  tokenServices.setSupportRefreshToken(true);
  tokenServices.setAccessTokenValiditySeconds(<seconds>);
  tokenServices.setClientDetailsService(clientDetailsService);
  return tokenServices;
}
```

& put this `tokenServices` in `AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer` like this.

```
@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
  endpoints.tokenServices(customTokenServices()).
}
```

Comment: In the class that extends 'AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter' I've used lines above. But 'TokenServices' didn't exist so I've used 'DefaultTokenServices' and I think it worked.

Comment: Thanks! It's really important to set *ClientDetailsService* in case you don't use in memory clients.

Answer (score 4):

You can set the expiry time of an access token during client configuration.
Changing values here will be updated in the jdbc token store.

```
public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.jdbc(dataSource)                        
                .withClient("my-client-with-password")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("password")
                .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT") 
                .scopes("read")
                .resourceIds("oauth2-resource")
                .accessTokenValiditySeconds(30);
```

For this you have to delete the the existing client details from the database. Next time a token call is made, these client details will be added into the database, along with your updated validity time.